# Why do we extend HTTPResponse in Django?

Tags: django

I am looking at [django-jquery-file-upload](https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload)

This is response file

```
MIMEANY = '*/*'
MIMEJSON = 'application/json'
MIMETEXT = 'text/plain'


def response_mimetype(request):
    """response_mimetype -- Return a proper response mimetype, accordingly to
    what the client accepts, as available in the `HTTP_ACCEPT` header.

    request -- a HttpRequest instance.

    """
    can_json = MIMEJSON in request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT']
    can_json |= MIMEANY in request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT']
    return MIMEJSON if can_json else MIMETEXT


class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
    """JSONResponse -- Extends HTTPResponse to handle JSON format response.

    This response can be used in any view that should return a json stream of
    data.

    Usage:

        def a_iew(request):
            content = {'key': 'value'}
            return JSONResponse(content, mimetype=response_mimetype(request))

    """
    def __init__(self, obj='', json_opts=None, mimetype=MIMEJSON, *args, **kwargs):
        json_opts = json_opts if isinstance(json_opts, dict) else {}
        content = json.dumps(obj, **json_opts)
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, mimetype, *args, **kwargs)
```

I do not understand how form_valid(views) is constructed.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save()
    files = [serialize(self.object)]
    data = {'files': files}
    response = JSONResponse(data, mimetype=response_mimetype(self.request))
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=files.json'
    return response
```

What is the benefit of using JSON response over HTTPResponse?

Comment: Other than the fact that it encodes the result as JSON for you?

Comment: The example serves for image upload.What is the benefit of JSON result?

Comment: ... JSON is what gives the World Wide Web power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well a `JSONResponse` is in fact a `HTTPResponse`. We only add some default functionality for **programmer convenience**, and to make it harder to make errors.

```
class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):

    # ...

    def __init__(self, obj='', json_opts=None, mimetype=MIMEJSON, *args, **kwargs):
        json_opts = json_opts if isinstance(json_opts, dict) else {}
        content = json.dumps(obj, **json_opts)
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, mimetype, *args, **kwargs)
```

The JSON response basically does two things:

1. it sets the `mimetype` by default to `application/json` such that if you do not provide it yourself, that is the MIME-type, and thus the browser (or other service that consumes the response), knows that this is a JSON response;
2. it automatically dumps Pyhon objects in a JSON-string (with `json.dumps(..)`). So instead of passing a JSON stream, you can pass a dictionary, and the `JSONResponse` will make sure it generates a valid JSON stream.

It also allows to pass specific parameters to this dump (the `json_opts`) to alter the dumping process a bit (for example dumping non-Vanilla Python objects).

It also makes it easier to add certain logic to *all* JSON responses. If for example later there is a JSON-2.0 standard, then we can rewrite the `JSONResponse` logic, and all `JSONResponse`s will use the new logic, instead of patching all occurrences in an *ad hoc* fashion.

But for a browser, there is no difference at all, since it only sees a HTTP response, with some values filled in. Whether these are filled in by the application programmer, or the Django library makes no difference.

JSON, is the **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation and is a popular format (like for example XML) to transfer data between applications. JavaScript, Python, Haskell, Java, etc. all have ways to encode and decode JSON. As a result it is typically used to transfer data between systems written in different languages (for example a browser runs JavaScript, and a Django webserver runs with Python).

In Django there is a lot of code that deals with programmer convenience. Take for example the `FormView`: it will make sure that the programmer does *not* have to initialize a `Form` itself, etc. This results in shorter and more elegant code, but also in less errors (since common parts are encapsulated in this class).

Answer (score 1):

From [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/)

If you find yourself needing a response class that Django doesn’t provide, you can create it with the help of http.HTTPStatus. For example:

```
from http import HTTPStatus 
from django.http import HttpResponse

class HttpResponseNoContent(HttpResponse):
    status_code = HTTPStatus.NO_CONTENT
```